# SKLEARN Bestfeatures.fit (X,Y), what does it mean? How do I define X and Y?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

my code doesn't work and I think it is because X and Y are not defined. I got the code from a book and it doesn't actually tell me how they are defined.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix


filename = '/Users/rahulparmeshwar/Documents/Algo Bots/Data/Live Data/Tester.csv'
data = read_csv(filename)

correlation = data.corr()

bestfeatures = SelectKBest(k=5)
fit = bestfeatures.fit(X,Y)

dfscores = pd.DataFrame(fit.scores_)
dfcolumns = pd.DataFrame(X.columns)
featurescores = pd.concat([dfcolumns,dfscores],axis=1)

pd.set_option('display.width',100)
data.head(1)
print(data)

scatter_matrix(data)
pyplot.show()

print(featurescores.nlargest('2,score'))
```

I've checked the documentation for SkLearn but it is not very helpful. Any Help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`X` and `y` should be the feature set and target variable that you loaded from your data file. This is one typical way to define them:

```
data = read_csv(filename)
y = data['target variable name']
X = data.drop('target variable name', axis=1)
```

Comment: Hello, It worked for y but for X it says its not found in axis. I changed it to 'Vol' because thats my column name. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Rahul2304 See my update. You have to specify `axis=1` to drop a column, otherwise it defaults to dropping rows.

Comment: Oh, I just seen it, I updated it, however now I'm ending up with 
'<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method' for fit=bestfeatures.fit(X,y)

Answer (score 0):

See this example here.

https://github.com/ASH-WICUS/Notebooks/blob/master/Accuracies%20of%20Different%20Regressors%20-%20Housing%20Prices.ipynb

You can download the sample code from here.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RuiChang123/Regression_for_house_price_estimation/master/final_data.csv

You should be able to get that working relatively easily. Then, modify the code to suit your specific needs. Remember, the 'X' consists of  your independent variables, and you want to measure which ones have an influence on the dependent variable, which is the 'y'.

This should help too!

https://mljar.com/blog/feature-importance-in-random-forest/